# AJAX vs. curl request header formatting -- header as object or string in JQuery?

Tags: ajax, curl

My API responds to the following curl request:

```
curl --data "session[email]=email@gmail.com&session[password]=password" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.my-app.v1' \http://my-app.dev/sessions
```

But not to this Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/sessions',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: 'Accept: application/vnd.superstar-is-back.v1',
    data: {
        session: {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
        },

    }
})
```

Am I getting something wrong with this syntax?

Comment: Can you add your `routes.rb`?

Comment: added routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this impacts Rails Routing, but based on the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), I think the `headers` property needs to be an object: `headers: { Accept: 'application/vnd.superstar-is-back.v1' }`

Comment: This was indeed the solution to my problem.